# keypress on datagridview only character "abcde" and convert to uppercase

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to limit `keypress` on `datagridview` only character **abcde** and convert to uppercase at vb.net?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing    
        If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
                AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBoxabcde_keyPress
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxabcde_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) And e.KeyChar <> "." Then
                e.Handled = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyPress
    Dim allLetters As String = "abcde"
    If Not allLetters.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As 
DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        e.Value = e.Value.ToString().ToUpper()
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get error in e.KeyChar = UCase(e.KeyChar), but keypress limitation is work for character abcde only

Comment: nice its work your code. but i'm try with other code with DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper

Answer (score 0):

another solution,im try with this, its work

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing    
            If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
                    DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
                    AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBoxabcde_keyPress
            End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxabcde_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
            If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
            Dim allowedChars As String = "ABCDE"
                        If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToUpper) Then
                                 e.Handled = True 
                        End If
            End If
    End Sub
```

thanks for your help Claudius

Comment: i would edit your question and post it there. Just don't delete your question so other people can learn

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim txtEC As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = Nothing
Private Sub DGV_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DGV.EditingControlShowing

If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl Then
    If DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex =1  Then
        txtEC = DirectCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        txtEC.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub DGV_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellEndEdit

If txtEC IsNot Nothing Then
      txtEC.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Normal
      txtEC = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```